# Scipy Guassian_kde Nomalisation

Tags: statistics, scipy, kernel-density, statsmodels

I've been using scipy.stats.gausian_kde but have a few questions about its output. I've plotted the normalised histogram and the gaussian_kde plot on the same graph. Why are the y-values so vastly different? My understanding is that the gaussian_kde plot should touch the tips of the histograms, roughly. Using the scipy.integrate.quad functions I determined the area under the graph to be 0.7, rather than 1.0, which is what I expected.

Actually what I really want is for the gaussian_kde to represent the non-normalised histogram, does anyone know how can I do that? [image: Graph here]

Answer (score 2):

Your expectations are a little off. The area under each of the KDE's peaks should roughly equal the area in their corresponding bars. That appears to hold, to my eye. Nonadaptive KDEs with a global bandwidth estimate (like `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`) tend to broaden multimodal distributions with sharp peaks.

As for the underestimate of the total area under the KDE, I cannot say without the data and the code that you used to do the integration.

In order to make a KDE approximate an unnormalized histogram, you need to multiply by `(bin_width*N)` where `N` is the total number of data points.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your answer. What is the bin-width of the KDE? Is it the same as the bandwidth? 

As for the integral, I simply did:

    ecdf = stats.gaussian_kde(array) followed by 
    scipy.integrate.quad(ecdf, min(array), max(array))

Comment: No, I meant the `bin_width` of the histogram that you are trying to match. Different histograms would have different normalization factors.

Don't use the minimum and maximum of the data as your integration bounds. KDEs smooth the data, so their support extends beyond the data. With pathological data like this, this extra extent is quite large.